# System freezes in a black screen before login screen shows up

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, freeze

I have been using Linux Mint 18 for a long time and it was working OK. But I upgraded it to Mint 18.3 and after restarting it, it freezes after Grub menu and doesn't open the login screen. I don't get any error messages, just a black screen.

To upgrade, I used update manager and selected update to 18.3 version.

Could someone please help me to solve this issue? I am very worried that I may lose my information in my laptop.

In grub menu I have these options:

1. Linux mint 18.3 cinnamon 64-bit
2. Advanced options for linux mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit
3. Memory test (memtest86)
4. Memory test (memtest 86 +, serial console 115200)
5. Windows 7

When I go to advance options and use root, I get the below output from `dmesg`:

```
tion="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=754 comm="apparmor_parser"
[25.572196] audit: type=1400 audit(1593517066.353:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation=profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=758 comm="apparmor_parser"
[25.606867] audit : type=1400 audit(1593517066.385:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=749 comm="apparmor_parser"
[25.607542] audit : type=1400 audit(1593517066.385:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=749 comm="apparmor_parser"
[25.608218] audit: type=1400 audit(1593517066.389:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=749 comm="apparmor_parser"
[25.608789] audit: type=1400 audit(1593517066.389:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script pid=749 comm="apparmor_parser"
[25.659262] audit: type=1400 audit(1593517066.437:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=748 comm="apparmor_parser"
[26.660207] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[26.660209] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[26.660212] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[241.758570] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
root@mehrana-K43SD ~ #
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to U&L. Do you have multiple options in your grub menu? There may be a rescue boot you can use to access your files. For a thorough answer, we would need to know what exactly you did to upgrade, along with any error messages you've received. Please can you [edit] your question to contain further information to help the community help you

Comment: I have added more details to my question now. @RobotJohnny

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say, what is causing your troubles, from the information you provided. If it doesn't show any error messages, it may be a problem with graphics drives or Xorg configuration. If you have some experience with Linux terminal, you can try second boot option in your GRUB and boot the Linux in the rescue mode. Then provide us logs from dmesg, xorg and graphics drivers. You can also try to connect to the SSH server if you have one configured in your system.

> I am very worried that I may lose my information in my laptop.

You will not lose your data. If you don't have experience with Linux or you just don't have time, you can always boot another Linux from the USB stick, **backup your data** to the external drive and then make a clean installation.

Comment: I have added more information.

Comment: It doesn't know xorg

Comment: I think this dmesg log you added is related to the currently running rescue mode. Check this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181067/how-to-read-dmesg-from-previous-session-dmesg-0).

Comment: "you can always boot another Linux from the USB stick, backup your data to the external drive. " 
Could you please provide a step by step solution?

Comment: @Marco The easiest way is to find a working computer, download some live Linux iso, extract it to a USB stick and make it bootable (software like Rufus or Etcher do this), then boot this live Linux on the broken computer and mount your local disk.

Comment: Is it possible to copy files to an external hard from boot? Do you know how?

Comment: @Marco What do you mean "from boot"?

Comment: Sorry, I ment from root

Comment: @Marco It should be possible even from rescue mode. But you have to do all work in the terminal. When you connect your external disk, you have to find his partition name with `lsblk`, then create a mount folder, for example, `mkdir /mnt/external`, and then mount this partition with `mount /dev/<name> /mnt/external`. Then you can start copying your data with `cd` or `rsync` commands to your external disk mounted in `/mnt/external`.

Comment: Once you are done, don't forget to `umount /mnt/external`.

Comment: Thank you so much. So I need to do "cp -r /home /mnt/external". Is this correct?

Comment: @Marco Yes, this will backup your whole home directory to the external drive. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to copy the whole directory like this, because there is a lot of config files, logs, caches, etc., and you may not want to copy them. But it's up to you. Also, make sure, you have enough free space on external disk. And when you finish, check if your data are stored on the external disk from another computer.

Comment: Are you aware of any TRUSTABLE step by step guide on how to  boot a live Linux on the broken computer and mount the local disk? I want it to be trustable so that I don't lose my information stored in the broken computer.

Comment: Also, it is possible to boot an Ubuntu on my broken Mint version?

Comment: @Marco It is possible to boot Ubuntu. Anything you want. Follow [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started). And remember, do not install anything. Just run in.

Answer (score 0):

`dmesg` says `EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted`... Your file system is probably having some troubles.

1. Boot another Live Linux from USB
2. Fix errors of your primary system partition(?):

   ```
   fsck.ext4 -fy /dev/sda5
   ```
3. Reboot

Comment: It makes me think why it doesn't signalize this filesystem errors in normal boot.